# Having trouble with "create-react-app" trying to connect to dev server

Tags: create-react-app, webpack-hmr

Good afternoon,

I have been trying to create a react app by following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0

The issue is, I can't seem to connect to the dev server. The page comes up and works fine, but I can't update anything. When I open the console on the server, all I see is "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..." Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this so I can get on with the tutorial?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing issue [github react link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8153)

Check some of the solutions from this link.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else that may see this, the answer that worked for me on the link salesh posted was this:  "npx create-react-app project-name --scripts-version 3.2.0" instead of the usual code.

Comment: no still its not working for me